# SP 2013 Search Page as directory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have been requested to create a search page that would display the addresses of my organization's locations. The idea is to have a list with all the locations and the search page will query from that list and display them. I am using SharePoint 2013 on-prem.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the `Query` in your `Search Result` to configure the `result source` as you prefer by doing the following:

- Edit your Search page.
- Edit the **Search Results Web Part:**.
- At search criteria, > click on Change Query.

[image]

- Add the result source for your location list as below

  ```
   {searchboxquery} path:"https://siteurl/list/*"
  ```

Comment: Thank you Qassas. I will try this and let you know if it works.

Comment: Take your time, hope it helps!

Comment: @Qassas, It's not pulling the items from the list. On the list i have these columns:
firstname, lastname, address, state, city, zip, phone number.

is there a way to change this to pull those items and display them in the search page?

Comment: when you try to search in the search box for a specific location. what happened ? what should be happened?

Comment: So the main idea is that if a user clicks on the [search] button that it will display every single item in the list. such as this: firstname, lastname, address, state, city, zip, phone number. Then they can search for a specific item and query that item only.

Comment: in this case, I think it's preferred to use the search box on the list itself! otherwise, you will need to customize the display template to show the result as a list!

Comment: That sounds like what I need to do. Do you know the steps or a link source where I can follow steps to get that accomplished?

Comment: Check this article http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2008/12/how-to-customize-sharepoints-core-search-results-web-part/ it's old one but should help